# Why does this automatic-storage structure still exist?

Tags: c++, stack, automatic-storage

### Code

`stack.h`:

```
struct customer
{
    char fullname[35];
    double payment;
};

typedef customer Item;

class Stack
{
private:
    ...
    Item items[MAX];
public:
    ...
    bool push(const Item & item);
    bool pop(Item & item);
};
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "stack.h"

...

int main()
{
    Stack s; double total;
    while (1)
    {
        ...
        cin >> c;
        switch (c)
        {
        case '1': push(s);
            break;
        case '2': pop(s, total);
            break;
        ...
        }
    }
    ...
}

void push(Stack & s)
{
    Item newitem;
    cout << "name -- ";    cin >> newitem.fullname;
    cout << "payment -- "; cin >> newitem.payment;
    s.push(newitem);
}

void pop(Stack & s, double & total)
{
    Item olditem;
    s.pop(olditem);
    total += olditem.payment;
}
```

---

### Remark

Most of `main()` is probably irrelevant, but I just want to show what I'm doing. `push()` and `pop()` are the important blocks.

The code above is supposed to fill a stack with `Item`s. When an `Item` is popped, its `payment` is added to a running `total`.

Also, differentiate between `Stack` methods `pop()` and `push()` with the functions in `main()`.

---

### Dilemma

**The code works exactly as I want it to, but I don't understand why...**

I create a local `Item` in the `push()` function. It is referenced and placed onto the `Stack`. However, when the `push()` function ends, shouldn't this local `Item` be removed since it is on automatic storage? Yet, somehow it still exists because when I call `pop()`, there it is.

Comment: Perhaps the code for push() in your Stack class creates a copy of your object and stores that copy in the items array

Comment: If you're referring to `Stack::push()`, no. It takes the address of the parameter. I have the implementation, and it doesn't look like it copies it: `items[top] = item;`.

Comment: Without seeing the code for `Stack::push` it's really impossible to say. But the comment by @nos is probably spot on.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `Stack::push` and `Stack::pop`?

Comment: Before we go down the road of "post this" "now post that", _stop_. Instead present your [MCVE], as the Help Centre instructed you.

Comment: @Sir Jony, that line is copying the object. Also your function takes a const reference, not an address.

Comment: What does the code do? What do you expect it to do? Please provide the *full* source code, the actual output, and the expected output. Free prose descriptions like "somehow it still exists because when I call pop(), there it is" are generally less useful then simple facts like "the program prints ABC while I expect it to print XYZ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `items[top] = item` uses the ***copy*** assignment operator to copy the structure.